# rotating documents in pdf file using java

Tags: java

I was stuck one issue i.e i am displaying pdf document using Iframe tag in my application.my requirement is i need to rotate the pdf document when the user clicked on rotate button.i have used the below code to achieve this one.

```
package com.resmac.ldms.action;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.text.ParseException;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;

import com.itextpdf.text.Image;

import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;


public class DocumentRotation {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, DocumentException, IOException {
          PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("C://Users//resmac//Desktop//rotate92.pdf"); 
          Document document = new Document(); 
          PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("C://Users//resmac//Desktop//rotate93.pdf")); 
          pdfWriter.setStrictImageSequence(false); 
 document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate()); 



document.open(); 

          int pageCount = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); 

          for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) { 

                  document.newPage(); 
                  PdfImportedPage page = pdfWriter.getImportedPage(pdfReader, i); 
                  Image image = Image.getInstance(page); 
                  image.setRotationDegrees(90); 
                  image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0); 
                  document.add(image); 
          } 
          document.close();
      }
}
```

when i run the above code document is rotating 90 degrees for first time.again if i run the same code by replacing the source document(with the output document which i got after first time execution) then document is rotating for 180.If i keep on doing the same every time i am getting the document with 180 degrees rotation.But my requirement is always it should always rotate only 90 degrees.Can any help me Please.I was stuck with this one since two days.Please help me:)

Comment: You could test the page orientation (with an `if`)

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is telling the page to be flipped 90 degrees regardless of what the viewer regards as up and down. When you flip it 90 degrees, the flipped image is the "normal" image and it will keep rotating to infinity.

You should have an *if* case and a boolean to test if the image already is flipped or not.

Example code:

```
boolean flipped = false;

if(!flipped){
   image.setRotationDegrees(90);
   flipped = true;
}
else if(flipped){
   image.setRotationDegrees(-90);
   flipped = false;
}
```

Comment: No Gemtastic it is not working.still it is rotating 180 Degrees for second time.my final code looks like below

Comment: for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) { 
      
              document.newPage(); 
              PdfImportedPage page = pdfWriter.getImportedPage(pdfReader, i); 
              Image image = Image.getInstance(page); 
            boolean flipped = false;

          if(!flipped){
             image.setRotationDegrees(90);
             flipped = true;
          }
          else if(flipped){
             image.setRotationDegrees(-90);
             flipped = false;
          }
              image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0); 
              document.add(image); 
      }

Comment: i have tried by placing this variable boolean flipped = false;  outside for loop also